# Informations about adding image to a video

Tags: python, image, opencv, video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to add an image to a pre-existing video in python. I haven't write any code yet, but I've done some research. Most of people seem to use OpenCV or ffmpeg to manipulate image and video.
So my questions are :

- Can we add images to video with OpenCV or ffmpeg?
- Can we do that without OpenCV or ffmpeg
- If yes, do you have some informations on it
- If no, should I use OpenCV or ffmpeg ? Maybe another ?
- Which version of OpenCV should I use ? and why ?
- I've read that they are a problem with OpenCV and Ubuntu, did they correct it ?

If you have some other informations or advice for me

Comment: As I know, it's not possible to add frame to video using OpenCV. You can only write new video with additional frame

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I already have a script to add a video to another video. So I think, I'm just gonna convert an image to a video with OpenCV, and finally add it to my video

Answer (score 0):

In OpenCV you could extract all the frames from the video and then use the VideoWriter class to create a new video from the frames plus your extra images. One issue I’ve had in the past using VideoWriter is using the correct video codec, you will have to do some research on this and see what’s compatible with your particular setup.

https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/dd/d9e/classcv_1_1VideoWriter.html

You may be able to do something similar with PIL (Python Imaging Library) although I’m not entirely sure on that. As for ffmpeg I’m also not sure.

The latest release of OpenCV would be sufficient for this. I currently have OpenCV 3.4 with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on a Virtual Machine and I have no problems using the VideoWriter class. Have a look at this blog post for advice on installing OpenCV on Ubuntu.

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/24/ubuntu-16-04-how-to-install-opencv/

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I think I'm gonna create a video with VideoWriter class and add this video to my other video. Thank you for the link, that will really help me !